# How to change default kit for Qt Creator Configure Project?

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator

When I start a new project (or delete the .pro.user file) the kit selection always defaults to "Desktop Qt 6.4.1 GCC 64bit". I have several other newer, and older kits available to select, but I always have to deselect 6.4.1 and select the one I want like 6.6.1. Where is this old version stuck as default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just

- open *Edit* -> *Preferences...* ,
- choose *Kits* from the left,
- choose *Kits* tab,
- select the kit you want to make default from the list, and
- finally click **Make Default** button.